# Tool to watch for WMI calls

Tags: windows, windows-7, wmi

I am doing some reverse engineering on a 3rd party program that is making some WMI calls to the namespace `Root\HP\InstrumentedBIOS`. Are there any tools similar to [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) that allows me to monitor WMI calls performed by another application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the specific application you have in mind, you might want to look into WMI logging/tracing as a way to gain more insight into WMI calls being made at run-time, e.g.:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2008/03/04/wmi-debug-logging.aspx

Comment: Looks promising, if it gets me the info I need you get the Checkmark.

Comment: It gets me close, but it what I really want is to observe the values of the parameters that is passed to a WMI method. I can see what methods are being called, but I can not see what is being passed in or what the return value was.

Comment: Throw the process in question under a debugger, perhaps?

Comment: That is my last resort, however without the source or debugging symbols doing it that way will be a slow process.

Answer (score 4):

Starting with windows vista you can use the [`Event Tracing for Windows (ETW)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968803%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the Event Viewer tool, check this MSDN article for more info [`Tracing WMI Activity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa826686%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score -5):

WMI Explorer by KS-Soft, is a tool that allows you to explore everything in WMI which includes management classes, objects and their properties on local or remote machines. It can be downloaded from [here](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm)

Comment: ...but I believe that Scott was looking for information about tracing calls at run-time, not being able to explore the WMI namespace.  No?

Comment: WMI Exploer does not monitor a running processes calls to a WMI provider, it only enumerates providers and can query them itself. It **can not** tell you what method calls (and what was passed in to the method) some other program made in to the WMI service. WMI Explorer is how I found the namespace.

Comment: The second thing you recommend is for VMWare Log files. How is that related to WMI Tracing?